# Getting class value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image, onclick on which I make some `ajax` requests.
I need to pass a variable from `$_GET[]` to my onclick function, so I decide to do the following:

```
<img id="img1" class="<?=$_GET['value']"?> />
```

and jQuery

```
$("#img1").click(function()
{
    // how can I get the class value here?
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pretty easily

```
$(this).attr('class');
```

FYI there are also dedicated class methods in jquery, such as [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) & [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: @Syom - protip - you don't need the full name with `@`, just the first word (as in @Ben) is sufficient for generating notifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr("class");
```

Also note that `$("#img")` wont really catch anything. These two, however, will:

```
$("img")
$("[id^=img]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).attr("class");`.

Unrelated: Undoubtedly, someone is going to comment on my answer to recommend caching the result of `$("#img")`.

Comment: you should cache the result of `$("#img")` :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr('class')
```